# Show Tab bar mid of screen in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin

I need to show Tab bar mid of screen for iphone and ipad. How I can achieve this. Check attached file.

[image]

Comment: You will need to find or write a custom control to do this.  The standard iOS tabbar is always at the bottom of the screen, per the iOS UI Guidelines.